# Intercept and cancel key press events for DirectX game

Tags: c#, c++, directx, keystroke

I'm working on a small tool for a DirectX game and I want to prevent the user from pressing a certain key (F12 in this case) for a certain period.

I could find many options for simulating keypresses but what are the options when it comes to nulling out a keystroke before the game reads it?

The language doesn't really matter, although I would prefer a C# or C++ solution, or just a nudge in the right direction :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the DirectX game yours, or is it third party (i.e. do you have the source code)? Also, what OS are you using?

Comment: @parrowdice No the game isn't mine and I don't have the source code. Its a third party game. I'm on Windows.

Comment: You probably want to look into [Window's Hooks API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632589(v=vs.85).aspx). This will allow to you intercept messages in the system before they arrive at the target window.

Answer (score 2):

The good news is, I've done this before so I can say that it is possible and it does work.

The bad news is that it's not simple. It requires a lot of complicated code, and will likely take a long time to implement, but I'll explain how you can do it.

Applications like DirectX games usually [register for raw input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645546%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
Since you want to stop a keyboard event from reaching the application, you need a way to insert your code between the raw input and the game so you can check the raw input and decide whether to allow it to be passed to the game:

So you want to change the flow from:

`Raw Input --> Game`

to

`Raw Input --> Your Code --> Game`

Without having access to the source code of the game, you have to find a way to insert your code.

When there is keyboard input available, the game will call the WinAPI function [GetRawInputData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645596%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which will tell it about the keyboard event. Ideally, what we want is when the game calls this function, it actually calls our code instead of the WinAPI function. Then we can decide what to tell the game about the keyboard event, we could tell it anything we want (e.g. ignore F12). Sounds great right? Here's where it gets interesting...

We can take advantage of how windows loads executables into memory. Typically, a program uses (or 'imports') calls to functions in other DLLs (such as `GetRawInputData`, in User32.dll). When the program gets loaded into memory, Windows will fill in a table (the Import Address Table (IAT)) with pointers to the executable code in the appropriate DLLs. This means that when the program calls the function, it gets directed to the executable code in User32.dll in memory to run it.

Wouldn't it be great if we could write/patch the address of one of our functions into that table, so that when the game calls `GetRawInputData`, it actually gets directed to our function for us to process? Well we can! It's called Import Address Table Patching.

There's a pretty good [article on it here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2082/API-hooking-revealed) with some working code in C++. You should first read it to understand in more detail how it works, then you can modify it to support your needs. It will work, but I know it's probably more work (much more work) than you would have been hoping for, but essentially you're hacking the application which is never easy to do.

It's worth doing, even just to gain a better understanding of Windows behind the scenes.

Good luck!

**EDIT**

As Simon said, Windows Hooks is a much simpler way to do it *if the game isn't using raw input*. DirectX Games tend to be a special case that don't really work too well with standard Hooks as they use special methods to get the input from the user. By all means give it a go though, it will be a lot easier if it works.

Comment: Wow thank you for the awesomely detailed answer! You got me really interested in the lower levels of Windows. IAT patching for instance sounds awesome. I will give Hooks a try as you suggested, however even if Hooks get the job done, I'm gonna try and implement your method just for the heck of it. It'll be a really good learning exercise. Thanks again :D